# Using asp:GridView to populate a form

Tags: asp.net

I am using an asp gridview element to do a search on the database and return some data using

```
    <asp:GridView ID="storedRecordsGrid" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"  emptydatatext="No data    available." runat="server">
```

So i have a gridview that gets popolated and each row has its own select event. When the user selects a row I want to use the data in that row to populate texboxes on my page.

```
    protected void OnRowCommand(GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        { 

        }
```

So I have this method and i have my textboxes but when the select even fires I am not sure how the data is stored for each colums of that selected row. what i want to have is something like.

```
    protected void OnRowCommand(GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        { 
         mytextbox.text=datagridcolumn.value   
        }
```

I am using .net 2.0 
and my c# code as of right now looks like this.

```
private DataTable fillGrid(string dComplainantFName,string dComplainantlName)
   {
        string server = "";
        using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(server))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ComplaintReportLookUp", cnx) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", dComplainantFName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", dComplainantlName);
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                cnx.Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error executing MyProcedureName.", ex);
            }
        }

    }
   protected void executeGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            storedRecordsGrid.DataSource = this.fillGrid(dComplainantFName.Text,dComplainantLName.Text);
            storedRecordsGrid.DataBind();
        }
    protected void OnRowCommand(GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        { 

        }
```

Thank you for your help

---

Thanks Tim for the help this is what ended up working for me.

```
    protected void gridSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var row = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
    //var cell1Text = row.Cells[0].Text; // should be your autogenerated select cell 
    dComplainantFName.Text = row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""); // Text in column 1 (the first column of your DataTable) 
    dComplainantLName.Text = row.Cells[2].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""); // Text in column 2 (the second column of your DataTable) 
    dComplainantMName.Text = row.Cells[3].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    dComplainantAddress.Text = row.Cells[4].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    dComplainantCity.Text = row.Cells[5].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    dComplainantState.Text = row.Cells[6].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    dComplainantZip.Text = row.Cells[7].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    dComplainantPhone.Text = row.Cells[8].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    storedRecordsGrid.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GridView's [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event, in the other events like `RowCommand` or `SelectedIndexChanging` the `SelectedRow` property is `null`. It's also the appropriate event for your requirement:

```
protected void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
    var cell1Text = row.Cells[0].Text; // is your autogenerated select cell(String.Empty)
    var cell2Text = row.Cells[1].Text; // Text in column 2 (the first column of your DataTable)
    var cell3Text = row.Cells[2].Text; // Text in column 3 (the second column of your DataTable)
    TextBox1.Text = cell2Text; // etc.
}
```

**Note**: If you wouldn't have set `AutoGenerateSelectButton` to true and have used `TemplateFields`, you ought to use `FindControl` on the `SelectedRow` to get a reference to your controls.

If you still insist on using `RowCommand`, you could get the selected row from the `CommandArgument`:

```
protected void Grid_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        var rowIndex    = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        var selectedRow = ((GridView)sender).Rows[rowIndex];
        var cell1Text   = selectedRow.Cells[0].Text; // is your autogenerated select cell(String.Empty)
        var cell2Text   = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text; // Text in column 2 (the first column of your DataTable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked like a charm i am not sure where you saw i was using rowcommand but i was able to make the datagrid populate the textboxes just by adding the onselectedindexchanged (a different command for 2.0?) and binding my textboxes to the cell array. Thank you so much for all of your help

Comment: @MichaelCole: Your event handler `OnRowCommand` showed it me. Btw, the [SelectedIndexChange event was already there in 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I'm glad to hear that it works.

Comment: oh yeah i ditched that and used the method you showed me. i will post the code that i ended up using so if anyone uses as a reference its not confusing